# Capturing an image wrapped around a mug with css using html2canvas results cut up

Tags: php, html, css, html2canvas

I'm trying to capture an image which i am first generating using CSS.

The CSS generated pic is like this..

[image]

and the current html2canvas output is...

[image]

Current Code i've tried is as follows...

```js
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture"), {
  allowTaint: true
}).then(canvas => {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #0000007a;
}

h1 {
  font: small-caps 167% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

#container {
  margin-left: -56px;
  top: 450px;
  width: 550px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

#container:hover * {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused
}

#frame {
  margin-top: 95px;
  width: 23px;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* translate must be last */
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-1deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-1deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(325px, -70px, 50px)
}

.strip {
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: spin 0.01s forwards;
}

.mastercontainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.strip div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000 url(http://automation.stickermonkey.shop/codeplayground/images/djmug2.jpg);
  border: solid rgb(145, 87, 0);
  border-width: thin 0;
  height: 275px;
  width: 34px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.strip .a {
  background-position: 0 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .b {
  background-position: 759px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .c {
  background-position: 726px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .d {
  background-position: 693px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .e {
  background-position: 660px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .f {
  background-position: 627px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .g {
  background-position: 594px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .h {
  background-position: 561px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .i {
  background-position: 528px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .j {
  background-position: 495px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .k {
  background-position: 462px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .l {
  background-position: 429px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .m {
  background-position: 396px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .n {
  background-position: 363px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .o {
  background-position: 330px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .p {
  background-position: 297px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .q {
  background-position: 264px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .r {
  background-position: 231px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .s {
  background-position: 198px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .t {
  background-position: 165px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .u {
  background-position: 132px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .v {
  background-position: 99px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .w {
  background-position: 66px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px)
}

.strip .x {
  background-position: 33px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px)
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(230deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="capture" class="mastercontainer">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="frame">
      <div class="strip">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
        <div class="d"></div>
        <div class="e"></div>
        <div class="f"></div>
        <div class="g"></div>
        <div class="h"></div>
        <div class="i"></div>
        <div class="j"></div>
        <div class="k"></div>
        <div class="l"></div>
        <div class="m"></div>
        <div class="n"></div>
        <div class="o"></div>
        <div class="p"></div>
        <div class="q"></div>
        <div class="r"></div>
        <div class="s"></div>
        <div class="t"></div>
        <div class="u"></div>
        <div class="v"></div>
        <div class="w"></div>
        <div class="x"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have put everything into a jsfiddle here..
https://jsfiddle.net/StickerMonkey/tLqrdey5/4/

EDIT TO ADD:
I have also tried `foreignObjectRendering: true` this gives the correct shape but is a blacked out image.

[image]

SECOND EDIT TO ADD;
I am also open to suggestions of another way to either wrap a rectangular image round a mug or another way to screenshot or otherwise grab the image i am already generating.

Comment: You could generate the 3D image straight on your canvas using a WebGL helper library such as three.js or p5.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using Three.js.

It creates a scene with a rotating view of the painted mug.

It also takes a snapshot at 60° rotation in a new canvas.

It also shows the paint alone in a third canvas with white background.

```js
//Moved to <script type="module">
//import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three';

function actualCode(THREE) {
  //Variables for rendering
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, 400.0 / 400, 1, 1000);

  //Object variables
  let texture;
  let paintedMug;

  //Preload image, then trigger rendering
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  //Real URL triggers cross origin error in tests:
  // texture = loader.load("http://automation.stickermonkey.shop/codeplayground/images/djmug2.jpg", function(_tex) {
  //Hosting it on local server works:
  // texture = loader.load("./djmug2.jpg", function(_tex) {
  //Example with image hosted from Imgur:
  texture = loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/TQZrUSP.jpeg", function(_tex) {
    // /*Debugging:*/ setTimeout(() => document.body.appendChild(texture.image), 100);
    init();
    snapShot(60);
    renderImageSolo(60);
    render();
  });
  
  function init() {
    //Init scene and camera
    camera.position.set(0, 1.3, 11);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    renderer.setSize(400, 400);
    addTitle("Animated scene:");
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    //Set an ambient light
    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    //Draw white mug
    const muggeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 240, 1);
    const mugmaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: "#fff",
    });
    const mug = new THREE.Mesh(muggeom, mugmaterial);

    //Draw painting on mug with slightly larger radius
    const paintgeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1.5001, 1.5001, 3.3, 240, 1, true);
    const paintmaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      map: texture,
    });
    const paint = new THREE.Mesh(paintgeom, paintmaterial);

    //Define a group as mug + paint
    paintedMug = new THREE.Group();
    paintedMug.add(mug);
    paintedMug.add(paint);
    //Add group to scene
    scene.add(paintedMug);
  }

  function render() {
    try {
      //Draw
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      //Rotate a bit at each frame
      paintedMug.rotation.y += -.01
      //Trigger next animation frame (default 60fps)
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, err.message);
    }
  }

  function snapShot(angle) {
    const orgAngle = paintedMug.rotation.y;
    //Rotate objects by angle
    paintedMug.rotation.y = angle;
    //render once
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    //Take still into new canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = renderer.domElement.width;
    canvas.height = renderer.domElement.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(renderer.domElement, 0, 0);
    canvas.style.marginTop = "1em"; //Space out canvas
    addTitle(`Snapshot at ${angle}°:`);
    document.body.append(canvas);
    //Restore rotation
    paintedMug.rotation.y = orgAngle;
  }

  function renderImageSolo(angle) {
    //Init just like main renderer / scene, will use same camera
    const solo_renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
    solo_renderer.setSize(renderer.domElement.width, renderer.domElement.height);
    solo_renderer.domElement.style.marginTop = "1em"; //Space out canvas
    addTitle(`Paint alone at ${angle}°:`);
    document.body.appendChild(solo_renderer.domElement);
    const solo_scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //Set an ambient light
    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff); // soft white light
    solo_scene.add(light);

    //Draw painting alone
    const paintgeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1.5, 1.5, 3.3, 240, 1, true);
    const paintmaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      map: texture,
    });
    const paint = new THREE.Mesh(paintgeom, paintmaterial);
    //Add paint to scene
    solo_scene.add(paint);
    //Rotate paint by angle
    paint.rotation.y = angle
    //Draw result
    solo_scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    solo_renderer.render(solo_scene, camera);
  }

  function addTitle(title) {
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    h2.innerText = title;
    document.body.appendChild(h2);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Below code is just a workaround for ES6 imports in SO snippet -->
<script type="module"> //Forced to put import in HTML section, as SO snippet does not support ES6 module loading
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three';
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _e => actualCode(THREE));
</script>
```

There were problems using your original image from another server due to CORS policy. I've setup the sample with a copy hosted on Imgur, but code for your original location is also included (see comments).

Comment: This is almost perfect, I just need to know how to save the image generated in the renderImageSolo(angle) function to tmp/images dir please as saving the image is why i was trying out html2canvas to begin with, i had already been able to display a wrapped img it was just the saving what i generate that was causing me the problems (and still is at this stage) Thanks again.

Comment: First, you can do it by saving manually: right click -> Save Image As... in Firefox. If you want to automate the process, then I'll need more details: how do you intend to use this script? One image at a time or a whole lot at once? Do you want to save it on server or on client?

Comment: You were trying to output to a canvas, so I guess you already had a plan for that.

Comment: Saving with right click was actually not working on the `solo_renderer` canvas. I've just fixed that by adding the option `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` when creating the `WebGLRenderer`

Comment: I did sus out the right click save thing but saving locally is not needed for what i'm doing to be honest, all I need to do is work out how to save the single generated image (the last one in your script that shows 3)  to the server (not locally) I am trying to work it out on my own but having not much luck so started a new question here stackoverflow.com/questions/68993912